# Shiny: How to embed a sidebarPanel inside tabPanel?

Tags: r, shiny, markdown

I'm trying to have a selecInput panel inside a sepecific tab and I'm not sure how to do that. Inside the function tabPanel() I have tried to include sidebarPanel() right after the function plotOutput () however the sidebarPanel isn't on the side anymore but instead on the left and overlaps the histogram plot. Would there be a way to embed properly that side panel in that particular tab or to get that side panel on the right side of the graph?
Thank you, below is the code I use:

```
mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Histogram",plotOutput("histogram")),
      tabPanel("Scatter",plotOutput("scatter"),
               sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("xaxis", label = "x axis",
              choices = detectors, selected = detectors[1],width='200px',selectize=FALSE),
  selectInput("yaxis", label = "y axis",
              choices = detectors, selected = detectors[2],width='200px',selectize=FALSE),
  selectInput("population1", label = "Population 1",
              choices = files, selected = files[1],width='200px',selectize=FALSE),
  selectInput("population2", label = "Population 2",
              choices = files, selected = files[1],width='200px',selectize=FALSE),
  selectInput("population3", label = "Population 3",
              choices = files, selected = files[1],width='200px',selectize=FALSE)
  )
),
      tabPanel("Table", DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
    )
)
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand the output with just the partial code. It's better if you provide a minimum reproducible example instead, of both server and UI.

Comment: You don't seem to have called sideBarLayout() anywhere...

Comment: sideBarLayout() was what I was looking for. Simple, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

your concept is right, but placement of code is wrong.  Go through following code which is self explanatory.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(


   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   tabsetPanel(               
           tabPanel("Tab 1", h1("First tab") ),
           tabPanel("Tab2",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(width = 3, sliderInput("bins",
                                                   "Number of bins:",
                                                   min = 1,
                                                   max = 50,
                                                   value = 30)
               ),
               
               mainPanel(
                 plotOutput("distPlot")
             )
           )
       )
   )
)
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
  
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```